# Half working Javascript function @LGSon

Tags: javascript, text

With the following function, I wish to make a text appear after an aumatically calculated value (by another function).
All the calculation are being done properly, but the text fails to show.

Here is the HTML context

```
<tr>
    <td>VALUTAZIONE INIZIALE</td>
    <td id="tota2" onchange="tota3()"></td>
    <td id="tota3"></td>
</tr>
```

And here is the related Javascript function:

```
function tota3() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('tota2').value);
    var y = document.getElementById('tota3');

    y.style.display = 'block';

    if (x >= 15){
        y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO BASSO";
    }
    else if (x < 15){
        y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO MODERATO"; 
    }
    else if (x < 11){
        y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO ALTO";
    }
    else if (x < 6){
        y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO ALTISSIMO";
    }
    else{
        y.innerHTML = "NaN';
    }
}
```

Comment: "All the calculation are being done properly" — What makes you think that? You are trying to call the function from an onchange event on a td (which doesn't have one) and then read the value of a td (which doesn't have one). td elements are not inputs.

Comment: `onchange` only works on TextBox, Radio/Check Box, and Select List. But not on `td`.

Comment: I posted the final HTML line of a long table. The calculation related to that table are working perfectly. The only thing amiss is the text (RISCHIO, etc)  that should show up once a specific result is obtained

Comment: @str so what should I use?
I already used the "onchange" on a <td> and it were working fine

Comment: The Id="tota2" is the sum of other calculations. I wish that, being those done and the result appear on the <td> field, the onchange function would kick in

Answer (score 0):

1) change :

```
 y.innerHTML = "NaN';
```

To :

```
y.innerHTML = "NaN";
```

2)insert tag table to code.

I fix It and change other sometings :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>VALUTAZIONE INIZIALE</td>
        <td oninput="tota3()"><input id="tota2" type="text" size="5"></td>
        <td id="tota3"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
          function tota3() {
              var txt = document.getElementById('tota2');
            var x = parseInt(txt.value);
              var y = document.getElementById('tota3');
               y.style.display = 'block';
               if (x >= 15) 
                   y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO BASSO";
              else
                  if (x < 6) 
                  y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO ALTISSIMO";
            
              else 
                  if (x >=6 && x < 11) 
                  y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO ALTO";
                  
              else
                  if (x >= 11 && x < 15) 
                  y.innerHTML = "RISCHIO MODERATO"; 
              
              else 
                  y.innerHTML = "NaN";
              
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @ehsan, but I'd like to build a page without buttons. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @NathanMantovani , yes i update it.use text in td.check my answer again.

Comment: @eshan Maybe I did not explain the situation clearly enough.
the td id="tota2"  in 
td id="tota2" onchange="tota3()"></td><td id="tota3"></td></tr>

is the result of a previous calculation. It doesn't need an input tag. I'd only like the text in id="tota3" to change according to the aformentioned sum